Minimization in Hilbert Space via two minimizations
Let V be a Hilbert and $ J : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex and continuous functional. I would like to prove that $J$ has a minimum.
My idea is to split the minimization in two steps by minimizing over the norm and the sphere.
Do i have the following results or i need more hypothesis ? My question is more about the equivalence between the decomposition of two minimum rather that the existence of the minimum of J per se.
$$\min_{v\in V} J(v) \text{ exists } \Leftrightarrow \min_{v\in V, \Vert v \Vert=1}\min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+} J(\lambda v) \text{ exists } $$
And if the minimum exists then,
$$\min_{v\in V} J(v) = \min_{v\in V, \Vert v \Vert=1}\min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+} J(\lambda v) =\min_{v\in V, \Vert v \Vert=1} J(\lambda_v^* v)$$
or
$$\operatorname{argmin}_{v\in V} J(v) = \operatorname{argmin}_{v\in V, \Vert v \Vert=1}\operatorname{argmin}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+} J(\lambda v) =\operatorname{argmin}_{v\in V, \Vert v \Vert=1} J(\lambda_v^* v)$$

I think there is a chance to prove equality of infima (you need to replace min by inf as there is no way to guarantee that the min exists).

Last line makes no sense: what is the argmin of an argmin?

Why did you delete your previous and identical question? Just to get rid of comments?

I reposted because I modified the question. If it was not the right thing to do I apologize.

The argmin of argmin is an abuse of notations. The first argmin meant that I found the right lambda and then I'm looking for the right v associated to this lambda, so in the end I will have lambda v

Here is an example that the first claim may fail: the $\min_v J(v)$ exists, but $\min_{\lambda \ge0}J(\lambda v)$ may not exist for some $v$:
Take $V= \mathbb R^2$, define
$$
f(x) = \max(0, \exp(x_2)+x_1).
$$
Then the minimum of $f$ exists ($f\ge0$ and $f(-1,0)=0$), but
for $v:=\pmatrix{0\\1}$
$$
\min_{\lambda} f( \lambda v)
$$
does not exist.

It seems that you are considering $x=(x2,x1)$ when i read your explanation for f(0,-1). Then $f(\lambda v) = \max(0,\lambda)$ and the minimum is 0 and argmin is $\lambda = 0$ no ?

thanks, should have been $f(-1,0)$.

Is there any assumptions i can make in order to make it true ?
